# php error while loading curl module

Tags: php

im getting error from php while trying to load curl module.

i have compiled curl module and added to php.ini

but unfortunately getting this error.

im using php on linux system 64 bit machine centos.

`PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Invalid library (maybe not a PHP library) '/root/php-5.6.5/ext/curl/modules/curl.so' in Unknown on line 0
Warning: PHP Startup: Invalid library (maybe not a PHP library) '/root/php-5.6.5/ext/curl/modules/curl.so' in Unknown on line 0
curl`

Answer (score 0):

i fixed the problem by adding `extension_dir = "/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20131226/"`

to php.ini